# How to deal with large figures in draft of a paper

Tags: journals, writing, graphics, formatting

I am working on a draft of a paper and I have large figure that does not fit into 1 page. I can split the figure into two, but I wonder what is the appropriate way of doing it.

Two ways that I consider:

1. Split the figure but pretend it is one large figure. That is page 1 would have headings first half of the figure and page 2 would not have headings but caption underneath.
2. Have the figure posted as two separate figures with both having separate headings and caption (would this make sense given I would essentially repeat the headings and captions?).

Is one of the two methods above more appropriate? Or is there a different way? Also, are there any good examples of published paper dealing with this problem?

Comment: It's more of a technical issue during the typesetting. The journal might have rules for this or the typesetter may handle this issue differently. In a similar situation, I did "Fig. 9: Evaluation, part 1" and "Fig. 10: Evaluation, part 2".

Comment: I've seen Supp. Fig. X, part 1 ... up to part 4 or so, so one figure stretching multiple pages. But this is not very nice and I only saw it once in a supplement. In the main text, you should really think about a) do I need to show all of this and b) do I need to show it this way.